# Voice AI Help Unicode not callable

Tags: python

Keeps saying unicode not callable how do i fix this?

Here is the code i am trying to execute

```
if 'weather forecast in' in command:
        reg_ex = re.search('weather forecast in (.*)', command)
        if reg_ex:
            city = reg_ex.group(1)
            weather = Weather()
            location = weather.lookup_by_location(city)
            forecasts = location.forecast
            for i in range(0,3):
                talkToMe('On %s will it %s. The maximum temperture will be %.1f degrees.''The lowest temperature will be %.1f degrees.' % (forecasts[i].date(), forecasts[i].text(), (int(forecasts[i].high())-32)/1.8, (int(forecasts[i].low())-32)/1.8))
```

I am using a mac so the terminal tells me that the unicode is not callable.

the error message i get in terminal

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled3.py", line 172, in <module>
    myCommand()
  File "Untitled3.py", line 42, in myCommand
    assistant(command)
  File "Untitled3.py", line 128, in assistant
    talkToMe('On %s will it %s. The maximum temperture will be %.1f degrees.''The lowest temperature will be %.1f degrees.' % (forecasts[i].date(), forecasts[i].text(), (int(forecasts[i].high())-32)/1.8, (int(forecasts[i].low())-32)/1.8))
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

Comment: Could you post the full error message?  It should include the line that caused the error.

Comment: here is the error message Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled3.py", line 172, in <module>
    myCommand()
  File "Untitled3.py", line 42, in myCommand
    assistant(command)
  File "Untitled3.py", line 128, in assistant
    talkToMe('On %s will it %s. The maximum temperture will be %.1f degrees.''The lowest temperature will be %.1f degrees.' % (forecasts[i].date(), forecasts[i].text(), (int(forecasts[i].high())-32)/1.8, (int(forecasts[i].low())-32)/1.8))
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Comment: What is the type of `forecasts[0].text` and `.date`?  If those are `unicode` objects, that would explain the error.

Comment: So how do i correct them because i am stuck in on that line right now?

Comment: You would remove the `()` after those items:  `int(forecasts[i].high)` instead of `int(forecasts[i].high())`

Comment: ok thanks I will test my code again